# execute global function automatically on running controller in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2, hook, helper

We have web pages, where user will be redirected to `$this->goHome()`, if the session timeouts or user logouts. We have to destroy the all the session so, we have to add a function with destroying session. This function should be executed before running any action/controller in Yii2 i.e. similar to hooks in codeigniter. We have tried a helper function with destroying session and we have called the function as `HomeHelper::getHelpDocUrlForCurrentPage();` in `main.php` layout, but the layout will be executed after running action in controller, it should work on running any controller as we have 100+ controllers. How this can be achieved, please suggest us in right way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
config/main.php
```

you could try using 'on beforeAction'

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',
        ....     
    ],   
    'on beforeAction' => function($event){
        // your code ..
    } ,
    'modules' => [
       ....
    ],
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

While @ScaisEdge solution would work I believe application config is not proper place to hold application logic.

You should use [filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters) to achieve result you want.

First you need to implement filter with your logic. For example like this:

```php
namespace app\components\filters;

class MyFilter extends yii\base\ActionFilter
{
    public function beforeAction() {
        // ... your logic ...
    
        // beforeAction method should return bool value.
        // If returned value is false the action is not run
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you want to attach this filter as any other [behavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors) to any controller you want to apply this filter on. Or you can attach the filter to application if you want to apply it for each action/controller. You can do that in application config:

```php
return [
    'as myFilter1' => \app\components\filters\MyFilter::class,
    // ... other configurations ...
];
```

You might also take a look at existing [core filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters#core-filters) if some of them can help you.